# GWT / RequestFactory - Object tree of response is not fully loaded although with() parameters seem ok

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm having the following problem when using GWT and request factory.

I am working on an object tree that is composed of different entities, say A references B and C, C references D.

I have a loadAs method that return the whole object graph using the with annotations (`with("B", "C", "C.D")`). So far everything looks great and i have the following structure loaded on the client.

```
A1
  -> B1
  -> C1
    -> D1
```

Now I create the following within a request context on the client.

```
A* (created on the client using context.create() )
  -> B1 (same B1 that was already loaded)
  -> C* (created on the client using context.create())
    -> D1 (same D1 that was already loaded)
```

My persist Method looks like this: `Request<List<A>> persistAs(List<A>)`

I fire it with the exact same with-parameters as loadAs (`with("B", "C", "C.D")`) but still my response looks like this:

```
A* (now contains an id that was created on the server)
  -> B1 (same as the previously loaded)
  -> C* (now contains an id that was created on the server)
      -> null
```

So, the D1 that already exists on the client is not part of the response's object tree. However, D1 is sent to the server and available in the persistAs method as part of the requests object tree. In addition, persistAs makes sure that the full object tree is returned (D1 is contained).

I have no clue why this happens. I also don't know where to debug. I don't get any exception.

Additional information or findings that I noticed while debugging and trying to nail this down:

- when I trigger loadAs on the client after they have been persisted, the full object graph is returned
- I am using objectify as persistency api
- C is a supertype that is abtract in nature, it is however implemented as a normal entity and its subtypes are too, as this concept works everywhere else i can't imagine that this is the problem. To be more precise: C is always a concrete subtype. The reference from C to D however is directly on the super type C. C and all its subtypes are marked as entity proxies and have corresponding server entities.
- For testing purposes i modified my server implementation of the persistAs method so that it internally calls loadAs after the As have been persisted. But then the client receives nothing at all?!? See the following code example for illustration:

  ```
  List<A> persistAs(List<A> As) {
     //Persist the As

     // Make sure the object graph of the As is loaded

     // return As;

     // Debug only - return As using loadAs -> the client receives nothing at all
     return loadAs(As);
  }
  ```

Comment: Peter, is `D1` root entity or it has parent entity (in GAE terminology) ? Also could you please show implementation of your [Locator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/Locator.html) ?

Comment: I am not using parents in my whole app... so it should be what you consider root entity. Here is the locator (God... I am not compatible with these formatting procedures here)  package com.typecase.todos.server.service;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ServiceLocator;

public class DAOServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

 public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
  try {
   return clazz.newInstance();
  } catch (InstantiationException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose (I fear) it might be a weird consequence of http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7189

Try `edit()`ing your D1 proxy (and B1 too, as you're at it) before you `fire()` the `RequestContext`.

Comment: I tried edit() ing D1 and B1. Unfortunately I get the same result.

Comment: I tried GWT 2.5 and still get the same error :-( Is it supposed to be fixed there?

Comment: As you can see in the issue tracker, no it's not fixed in 2.5 RC1. And given how hard it would be to fix it (from my quick look at it the other day), it probably won't be in 2.5.0 or 2.5.1. The workaround worked for others having this issue though, so you might be facing a different issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a simple project reproducing the issue and posting it somewhere? (Google Groups for GWT, or open an issue in the tracker and attach the project there) That would help me debug what's wrong and fix RequestFactory if needed.

Comment: Hi Thomas, here you go: https://github.com/peteraschenbrenner/RFDebug; just contact me if you have any questions. THX

Comment: OMG,sharing a project without using some dependency-management tool? really?! Would you mind converting it to Maven or whatever so I could just "git clone + import in Eclipse + Debug as web app" rather than "git clone, download this, download that, import in Eclipse, configure that, then it should work, if you're lucky"

Comment: Sorry... I know nothing of Maven. I included all non App-Engine, GWT dependent jars in the project. They are in the war/lib folder. I was hoping it works "out of the box" when you import the project as AppEngine + GWT Project (I used the 2.5 RC GWT). Obviously it doesn't. Looks like I need to learn Maven now :-) Or... could somebody help? THX ... btw: Thomas: really appreciate your work for GWT!!!

Comment: Thing is: you suppose I installed/downloaded AppEngine and GWT SDK and configured them in Eclipse. Will try to find time to set them up in an Eclipse to test your code; will just take a bit more time.

Comment: OK, setup and launched. I had a few errors, unrelated to your issue (`loadAllAs` would return an empty list); then I restarted DevMode and set a breakpoint to inspect the list before it's returned by the server (everything was OK) and when resuming execution it all worked without error (using GWT 2.5.0-rc1)

Comment: OK, just to be sure... so you get a loadedVt in line 103 in RfDebug.jar? For me it is always null. Thats the only thing thats not working for me. The rest is ok. The code doesn't throw an exception or so... However, because it is not working I have to completely reload most of the entities that I modified on the server, which creates a completely unnecessary 2nd roundtrip. THX Peter

Comment: Given my observation, you might simply have an issue with "eventual consistency"; maybe try using Objectify's _session cache_ (you should really use it, when using RequestFactory). I'll try executing the project again, later.

Comment: OK; I've removed Objectify to store everything in a global, static Map; and I can reproduce the error, which is that 2 instances of `ConcreteVProxy` get created; one has its `vt` populated, the other not, and of course it's that other proxy that gets assigned to the `AProxy`.

Comment: Thx. Again... To be sure: do i have an error in the persistence layer and create the concrete vproxy twice or is it something that requestfactory does? Thx peter

Comment: It's in the decoding of the response, on the client side. The same `EntityProxyId` leads to 2 proxies being created :-(

Comment: Thx... I really owe you a beer or two for that. At least knowing that it should work is a bit of a relief. Whats the best way to proceed? Open an issues in the Google Bug Tracker? Any ideas on how to fix that?